# How to exclude files for compilation but include for testing in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

File structure

functions/lib/src/...src .ts files
functions/lib/test/...test files
functions/tsconfig.json

When I include test files directory in the tsconfig.json.include property linting works fine in my test files. However when I run tsc the test files are compliled into js.

When I remove the test directory from the tsconfig.json include property i get errors in my test files for all Jest methods like the following:

> Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a
>   test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

tsconfig.json looks as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],

}
```

jest.config.js looks as follows

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

How can I get Jest method recognition and not be stuck with compiling the test files?

Comment: Did you fix it? It's very strange there isn't a simple and known answer to something that seems so common.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-exclude-test-files-from-compilation) has a solution that worked for me.

You create a `tsconfig.build.json` file that extends your `tsconfig.json` file, with the following content:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  // ️ this may vary depending on how you
  // name your test files
  "exclude": [
    "lib/test/*",
  ]
}
```

Then, your normal `tsconfig.json` is used for the test runner, and to transpile your files, use the command:

```
tsc --project tsconfig.build.json
```

You can add that command as a script in the `package.json` as the build command.